# What are the sudoers file?

Tags: linux, hadoop

Why hduser created for hadoop is not permitted to access sudo commands?......

hduser@raj-SVE15115ENB:~$ sudo gedit /home/hduser/.bashrc
[sudo] password for hduser: 
hduser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Type `man sudo` then `man sudoers`

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered you own question... hduser needs to be in the sudoers file. You can find it here `/etc/sudoers` or alternatively you can edit it with `visudo`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` command provides temporary privilage escalation to users and configuration file associated with this command is `sudoers`. You can find this file in `/usr/local/etc/sudoers` or sometimes in `/etc/sudoers`. This file contains various configuration options including which users should be given `sudo` previlages. By the way you do not need `sudo` permission to access your own `bashrc`. You can read more on [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo)

Answer (score 0):

You have created hduser for hadoop, but hduser does not have privilage to use sudo. You have to give  privilage to hduser by execute commands, to open file (on hadoop/root user terminal)

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

edit in file

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
hduser  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

hduse give the privilege like root

Answer (score 0):

log in as root user and give privileges to the user 
 type visudo command and  identify the line ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
then attach this line next to that (user name) ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
start using sudo commands.